# What happens to Peggy Olsen's baby?

Tags: mad-men

I have gone through 1 1/4 seasons of Mad Men. I saw the nurse take the baby away from a disinterested Peggy.

I am not asking for a spoiler. I would like to know if they had simply let the future of the baby hang as a mystery, or if the child would emerge in later seasons.

Comment: Just decided this is better as a comment - Peggy's baby, or the mystery of it, is an important plot point throughout a few later episodes. Any information would be a spoiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The baby does not disappear from the series. All I can tell you. No point in writing any spoilers.

Comment: Um... then this isn't really an answer?

Comment: I think this does answer the question. The OP was asking for a single piece of information and requested to have no spoiler details.

Comment: ahh, you would be correct mary jo.  sadly i can't take away my downvote....

Answer (score 1):

There's some misdirection that implies the fate of the baby, which you'll get to later on as you progress through the show.  This makes it a little hard to give a straight yes/no answer to your question, since you request no spoilers.  If you do want it spoiled:

> [This interview](http://featuresblogs.chicagotribune.com/entertainment_tv/2008/10/mad-men-peggy-b.html) with the show's creator explains the baby's fate.  It's implied that Peggy's sister maybe takes the baby to raise it.  But that's not the case, the baby is put up for adoption, and we never see it again.

There is some dialogue later on that does discuss the baby and what happened to it.  So, this plot thread didn't just get dropped, it does return.